# Generating ASCII coverage file for covergroup

Tags: system-verilog, test-bench

I have some cover groups in my testbench driver. I want to generate a coverage results file, not ucm type but ASCII type, so I can feed it to a spreadsheet or Python.

I work with the Cadence Xcelium simulator.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Cadence documentation.  You can read in the coverage database then use the `report` command with the `-text` option to output a coverage report file in plain text format.

Alternately, you can use the `covergroup` `get_inst_coverage` and `get_coverage` methods in your Verilog source code files along with `$display` to output the coverage results to the simulation log file.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 19.8 *Predefined coverage methods*.  The advantage to this approach is that it works with any simulator.